# Heuristic explanation for Ito integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Take as an example the computation of one of the basic Ito integrals, namely $\int^T_0XdX=\frac{1}{2}(X^2(T) -T)$, where X is the usual Wiener process.

Do we have any heuristic explanation for the $-T$ term? Why the introduction of the stochastic evolution (i.e. the non-derivability of the function) *lowers* the result by a factor equal to the lenght of the interval?

The math is clear to me but I woiuld like to get an insight, if it exists.

Comment: That is the difference between Stratonovich integral and Ito integral...

Comment: I know it very well, I was just asking for an heuristic insight on it. Thank you!

Comment: I ask you to avoid writing a whole answer about something you already know about; do you know the connection between Ito integral, Wick products and Wick ordering of non commutative operators?

Comment: Not really, I know about Wick ordering from quantum field theory but not in connection with Ito Integral. Does this connection help to get the heuristic insight I was asking for?

Comment: In a certain sense it's the same thing. The Itô integral can be interpreted as a Hitsuda-Skorkhod integral i.e. $\int_0^T B_s dB_s=\int_0^T B_s\diamond \dot B_s ds$, where $\diamond$ is the Wick product. The Wick product  is to stochastic integration as the standard product is to standard integration, this means that the result of integral above can be writen as $B_T^{\diamond 2}$.

Comment: You can now see this in terms of operators, think of $B_T$ as the multiplication operator, then use the fact that the multiplication operator is the sum of a creation and a annihilation operator. The "Wick" square is then a sort of Wick ordering and then you can use the commutation relations to see that you arrive to $B_T^2-T$. Another way to look at this is to use the fact that for Gaussian random variables the $n$-th Wick power corresponds to the $n$-th (probabilistic) Hermite polynomial.